# How to fix "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found"?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I was making a program that finds the products and sends the message with telegram.

This is the mechanism:

1. User inputs the resendTerm, categories, productname
2. It goes to the used trading site
3. Clicks the categories bar
4. Find the categories which user inputed and click
5. Find the products which user inputed
6. Sends the screenshot of product and link with telegram
   loops all the steps with term which user inputed `resendTerm`
   and this error happened

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\공지훈\testtesttest.py", line 76, in <module>
    check_products()
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\공지훈\testtesttest.py", line 32, in check_products
    if selectedCategories in categories_titles[i].text:
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 90, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)["value"]
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
  (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.111)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00FA37C3+48947]
        (No symbol) [0x00F38551]
        (No symbol) [0x00E3C92D]
        (No symbol) [0x00E45D41]
        (No symbol) [0x00E40056]
        (No symbol) [0x00E3F22F]
        (No symbol) [0x00E4106A]
        (No symbol) [0x00E41110]
        (No symbol) [0x00E666FD]
        (No symbol) [0x00E8508C]
        (No symbol) [0x00E62EB6]
        (No symbol) [0x00E853E4]
        (No symbol) [0x00E975DA]
        (No symbol) [0x00E84E86]
        (No symbol) [0x00E616C7]
        (No symbol) [0x00E6284D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011EFDF9+2458985]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0123744F+2751423]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01231361+2726609]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01020680+560624]
        (No symbol) [0x00F4238C]
        (No symbol) [0x00F3E268]
        (No symbol) [0x00F3E392]
        (No symbol) [0x00F310B7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75C600C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77687B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77687AEE+238]
```

This is the full code.

I searched for the error message and I tried to use `expect StaleElementReferenceExpection` but it didn't work.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import telegram
import asyncio
import time

def check_products():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    driver.set_window_size(1275, 1080)
    driver.set_window_position(280, 30)

    driver.get(url='https://m.bunjang.co.kr/')

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
    element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > div > div > div.sc-dfVpRl.fxYqEy > div.sc-gzOgki.ciqSeg > div.sc-kPVwWT.gwGdGE > div.sc-fBuWsC.gIJOQQ > img')
    action.move_to_element(element).perform()

    categories_titles = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > div > div > div.sc-dfVpRl.fxYqEy > div.sc-gzOgki.ciqSeg > div.sc-kPVwWT.gwGdGE > div.sc-fBuWsC.gIJOQQ > div > div > div.sc-fAjcbJ.cROcun > a')
    categories_urls = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > div > div > div.sc-dfVpRl.fxYqEy > div.sc-gzOgki.ciqSeg > div.sc-kPVwWT.gwGdGE > div.sc-fBuWsC.gIJOQQ > div > div > div.sc-fAjcbJ.cROcun > a')

    for i in range(len(categories_titles)):
        if selectedCategories in categories_titles[i].text:
            message = categories_titles[i].text + "\n" + categories_urls[i].get_attribute('href')
            print(message)
            driver.get(categories_urls[i].get_attribute('href'))

            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            try:
                product_titles = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div.sc-ESoVU.jOTkNQ > div > div:nth-child(n+1) > a > div.sc-iGPElx.iPIFfd > div.sc-kasBVs.hJbjqV')))
                product_urls = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div.sc-ESoVU.jOTkNQ > div > div:nth-child(n+1) > a')))
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                continue

            product_elements = list(zip(product_titles, product_urls))

            for product_title, product_url in product_elements:
                try:
                    product_title_text = product_title.text
                except StaleElementReferenceException:
                    continue

                if selectedName in product_title_text:
                    message = product_title_text + "\n" + product_url.get_attribute('href')
                    print(message)
                    driver.get(product_url.get_attribute('href'))
                    driver.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
                    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
                    asyncio.run(bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo='screenie.png', caption=message))
    time.sleep(resendtime)

bot_token = '6037030120:AAHUN_wBLpfOOokYtXiINGhvWlFM6A6LEYs' # 텔레그램 봇 API
bot = telegram.Bot(bot_token) # 텔레그램 봇 정의
chat_id = '6580870338' # 텔레그램 봇 챗 id 

print("원하는 재전송 시간을 입력해주세요. : ")
resendtime = int(input())
print("원하는 상품의 카테고리를 입력해주세요: ")
selectedCategories = input()
print("상품의 이름을 입력해주세요: ")
selectedName = input()

max_iterations = 10
ttt = 0

while ttt < max_iterations:
    check_products()
    print(ttt)
    ttt += 1

print("종료합니다.")
```

Comment: You can't use a .get() while iterating the webelement reference array.  After using that this will fail: categories_urls[i].get_attribute()... as the whole array is stale.  Get all the hrefs is the loop, store those as array of strings...  then iterate through the strings to use them in  driver.get() calls.